# Generating formated flat file

Tags: python, for-loop, formatting

I want to generate a File, where measured data is stored in a specific format.
This is the code that is generating the file:

```
channels = [0, 1, 2]
try:
samples_per_channel = 0
end_time = time.time() + measure_time
text_file = open(RawDataName + ".txt", "a")
text_file.write(f"{'Measure':>7{'Channel_0':>8}{'Channel_1':>8}{'Channel_2':>8}\n")
while time.time() <= end_time:
    with open(RawDataName + ".txt", "a") as text_file:
        for channel in channels:
            value = hat.t_in_read(channel)
            text_file.write(f"{samples_per_channel:05d}{value:2.4f}\n")
    stdout.flush()
    sleep(1)
```

The resulting file isn't ordered the way the first line intends it to do.
the desired output file should look like:

```
Measurment  Channel 0   Channel 1   Channel 2   
1           19.5        19.5        19.5
2           20          20          20
3           19.5        19.5        19.5
```

I read through the documentation and some posts on this side but can't figure out how to construct the **for** loop so it behaves the way I want.

Edit:
The current code results in a file with the following structure:

```
Measurment Channel0 Channel1 Channel2 
0000119.9842
00001-9999.0000
0000219.9842 
00002-9999.0000
0000319.9993
00003-9999.0000
0000419.9921
00004-9999.0000
0000520.0005
00005-9999.0000
```

Edit 2:
All the line

```
value = hat.t_in_read(channel)
```

does, is to read an input channel and give back a float number.

Comment: What does the output file actually look like instead of what's desired?

Comment: You could start by adding some spaces between the values.

Comment: Tried to do that but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main problem is this line:

```
text_file.write(f"{samples_per_channel:05d}{value:2.4f}\n")
```

Firstly you write `samples_per_channel` - why? It isn't part of your desired output. Then you write `value`, which is fine, but then `\n` - a newline. Instead of the `\n` at the end you should write a `\t` (tab) in the beginning. Then write the measurement index directly before the `for`-loop and a newline directly after and you're done.

I would suggest you additionally switch the `while`-line with the `with`-line - as it stands, you`re opening and closing the file for each measurement.